# Adding Bokeh slider makes dashboard blank

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to add a slider to filter the cities that show up on a map of the world. When i just add all cities with the code below it works fine.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import geopandas
import geoplot
import json

from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, output_file
from bokeh.models import  (NumeralTickFormatter, Select, CDSView, ColorBar, ColumnDataSource,
                          CustomJS, CustomJSFilter,
                          GeoJSONDataSource, HoverTool,
                          LinearColorMapper, Slider)
from bokeh.io.doc import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column, row, widgetbox
from bokeh.palettes import brewer
from bokeh.plotting import figure, Figure


world = geopandas.read_file(
    geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres')
)
bokeh_ready = json.dumps(json.loads(world.to_json()))

geosource = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson = world.to_json())

cities = pd.read_csv('/Users/620751/Documents/cities.csv')


geocities = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson = cities[['Leg_Orig', 'Leg_Dest', 'MAILG_CTY_NM', 'MAILG_ST_CTRY_NM',
       'Leg_Dep_Dt', 'Opr_Car_Flt_Nbr', 'Leg_Dep_Tm','Leg_Arrv_Dt_Tm',
       'Opr_Car_Cd', 'Leg_Dep_Dt_Tm', 'd1_avail', 'cp_avail', 'mn_avail',
       'ot_avail', 'total_seats', 'dest_lat', 'dest_long', 'geometry']].to_json())

cities_input = cities[['Leg_Orig', 'Leg_Dest', 'MAILG_CTY_NM', 'MAILG_ST_CTRY_NM',
                       'Leg_Dep_Dt', 'Opr_Car_Flt_Nbr', 'Leg_Dep_Tm', 'Leg_Arrv_Dt_Tm',
                       'Opr_Car_Cd', 'Leg_Dep_Dt_Tm', 'd1_avail', 'cp_avail', 'mn_avail',
                       'ot_avail', 'total_seats', 'dest_lat', 'dest_long', 'geometry', 'duration_hours']]


p1 = Figure(title = 'Flights', 
           plot_height = 720 ,
           plot_width = 1200, 
           toolbar_location = 'below',
           tools = 'pan, wheel_zoom, box_zoom, reset')

p1.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p1.ygrid.grid_line_color = None# Add patch renderer to figure.

countries = p1.patches('xs','ys', source = geosource,
                   fill_color = None,
                   line_color = 'gray', 
                   line_width = 0.25, 
                   fill_alpha = 1)# Create hover tool

p1.add_tools(HoverTool(renderers = [countries],
                      tooltips = [('Country','@name')]))


cities_input = cities[['Leg_Orig', 'Leg_Dest', 'MAILG_CTY_NM', 'MAILG_ST_CTRY_NM',
       'Leg_Dep_Dt', 'Opr_Car_Flt_Nbr', 'Leg_Dep_Tm','Leg_Arrv_Dt_Tm',
       'Opr_Car_Cd', 'Leg_Dep_Dt_Tm', 'd1_avail', 'cp_avail', 'mn_avail',
       'ot_avail', 'total_seats', 'dest_lat', 'dest_long', 'geometry','duration_hours']]





city_source = ColumnDataSource(cities.drop('geometry', axis=1))
city_pt = p1.circle('dest_long', 'dest_lat', source = newsource,
                       color='red')

p1.add_tools(HoverTool(renderers = [newsource],line_policy='next',
                          tooltips = [('City','@MAILG_CTY_NM'),
                                     ('Departure Time','@Leg_Dep_Dt_Tm'),
                                     ('Seats','@seats'),
                                     ('Flight Time','@duration_hours' + ' hours'),
                                     ('weather', '@weather_desc' + ' low:' + '@low_temp' + ' high:' + '@high_temp' + ' rain:' + '@rain')]))


layout = column(p1)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

When I try to add a slider so I can filter what cities show on the map(based on flight time from base city using column 'duration_hours' I tried to change my code to this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import geopandas
import geoplot
import json

from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, output_file
from bokeh.models import  (NumeralTickFormatter, Select, CDSView, ColorBar, ColumnDataSource,
                          CustomJS, CustomJSFilter,
                          GeoJSONDataSource, HoverTool,
                          LinearColorMapper, Slider)
from bokeh.io.doc import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column, row, widgetbox
from bokeh.palettes import brewer
from bokeh.plotting import figure, Figure


world = geopandas.read_file(
    geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres')
)
bokeh_ready = json.dumps(json.loads(world.to_json()))

geosource = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson = world.to_json())

cities = pd.read_csv('/Users/620751/Documents/cities.csv')

#cities = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(lat_long1, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(lat_long.dest_long, lat_long.dest_lat))
cities['Leg_Arrv_Dt_Tm'] = [str(a) for a in cities['Leg_Arrv_Dt_Tm']]
cities['Leg_Dep_Dt_Tm'] = [str(a) for a in cities['Leg_Dep_Dt_Tm']]
cities['Leg_Dep_Dt'] = [str(a) for a in cities['Leg_Dep_Dt']]
cities.Leg_Dep_Tm = [str(a) for a in cities['Leg_Dep_Tm']]
geocities = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson = cities[['Leg_Orig', 'Leg_Dest', 'MAILG_CTY_NM', 'MAILG_ST_CTRY_NM',
       'Leg_Dep_Dt', 'Opr_Car_Flt_Nbr', 'Leg_Dep_Tm','Leg_Arrv_Dt_Tm',
       'Opr_Car_Cd', 'Leg_Dep_Dt_Tm', 'd1_avail', 'cp_avail', 'mn_avail',
       'ot_avail', 'total_seats', 'dest_lat', 'dest_long', 'geometry']].to_json())

cities_input = cities[['Leg_Orig', 'Leg_Dest', 'MAILG_CTY_NM', 'MAILG_ST_CTRY_NM',
                       'Leg_Dep_Dt', 'Opr_Car_Flt_Nbr', 'Leg_Dep_Tm', 'Leg_Arrv_Dt_Tm',
                       'Opr_Car_Cd', 'Leg_Dep_Dt_Tm', 'd1_avail', 'cp_avail', 'mn_avail',
                       'ot_avail', 'total_seats', 'dest_lat', 'dest_long', 'geometry', 'duration_hours']]


p1 = Figure(title = 'Flights', 
           plot_height = 720 ,
           plot_width = 1200, 
           toolbar_location = 'below',
           tools = 'pan, wheel_zoom, box_zoom, reset')

p1.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p1.ygrid.grid_line_color = None# Add patch renderer to figure.

countries = p1.patches('xs','ys', source = geosource,
                   fill_color = None,
                   line_color = 'gray', 
                   line_width = 0.25, 
                   fill_alpha = 1)# Create hover tool

p1.add_tools(HoverTool(renderers = [countries],
                      tooltips = [('Country','@name')]))

cities_input = cities[['Leg_Orig', 'Leg_Dest', 'MAILG_CTY_NM', 'MAILG_ST_CTRY_NM',
       'Leg_Dep_Dt', 'Opr_Car_Flt_Nbr', 'Leg_Dep_Tm','Leg_Arrv_Dt_Tm',
       'Opr_Car_Cd', 'Leg_Dep_Dt_Tm', 'd1_avail', 'cp_avail', 'mn_avail',
       'ot_avail', 'total_seats', 'dest_lat', 'dest_long', 'geometry','duration_hours']]

def json_data(duration):
    dur = duration
    df_dur = cities_input[cities_input['duration_hours'] <= dur]
    dur_json = json.loads(df_dur.to_json())
    json_data = json.dumps(dur_json)
    return json_data

newsource = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson = json_data(24))

def update_plot(attr, old, new):
    yr = slider.value
    new_data = json_data(yr)
    newsource.geojson = new_data


slider = Slider(title='Duration', start=0, end = int(np.round(cities.duration_hours.max(),0)), step=1, value=12)


city_pt = p1.circle('dest_long', 'dest_lat', source = newsource,
                       color='red')

p1.add_tools(HoverTool(renderers = [newsource],line_policy='next',
                          tooltips = [('City','@MAILG_CTY_NM'),
                                     ('Departure Time','@Leg_Dep_Dt_Tm'),
                                     ('Seats','@seats'),
                                     ('Flight Time','@duration_hours' + ' hours'),
                                     ('weather', '@weather_desc' + ' low:' + '@low_temp' + ' high:' + '@high_temp' + ' rain:' + '@rain')]))

slider.on_change('value', update_plot)

layout = column(p1,widgetbox(slider))
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Instead of a map with all the cities shown as red dots I get a blank screen. I'm not sure what dumb mistake I am making but I hope someone might?

Comment: Are there any messages in the browser's JavaScript console? FYI for any recent version of Bokeh just use `column(p, slider)` there is no need for `widgetbox` (and it will soon be deprecated)

Comment: There is an error but it is because of the hovertool code. When I commented out the hovertool there is no error but the page is still blank.

Comment: If you can make a complete, minimal, self-contained example version of this code that can be copy-pasted and run by anyone else, I am happy to try running/debugging it myself. Otherwise there is not much I can say just from looking at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp, I had to rewrite a bit of it but I got it working correctly. Credit to towardsdatascience where I stole the code template from.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import geopandas
import geoplot
import json

from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, output_file
from bokeh.models import  (NumeralTickFormatter, Select, CDSView, ColorBar, ColumnDataSource,
                          CustomJS, CustomJSFilter,
                          GeoJSONDataSource, HoverTool,
                          LinearColorMapper, Slider)
from bokeh.io.doc import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column, row, widgetbox
from bokeh.palettes import brewer
from bokeh.plotting import figure, Figure
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, DateFormatter, TableColumn

world = geopandas.read_file(
    geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres')
)
bokeh_ready = json.dumps(json.loads(world.to_json()))

geosource = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson = world.to_json())

cities = pd.read_csv('/Users/620751/Documents/cities.csv')

#cities = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(lat_long1, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(lat_long.dest_long, lat_long.dest_lat))
cities['Leg_Arrv_Dt_Tm'] = [str(a) for a in cities['Leg_Arrv_Dt_Tm']]
cities['Leg_Dep_Dt_Tm'] = [str(a) for a in cities['Leg_Dep_Dt_Tm']]
cities['Leg_Dep_Dt'] = [str(a) for a in cities['Leg_Dep_Dt']]
cities.Leg_Dep_Tm = [str(a) for a in cities['Leg_Dep_Tm']]
geocities = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson = cities[['Leg_Orig', 'Leg_Dest', 'MAILG_CTY_NM', 'MAILG_ST_CTRY_NM',
       'Leg_Dep_Dt', 'Opr_Car_Flt_Nbr', 'Leg_Dep_Tm','Leg_Arrv_Dt_Tm',
       'Opr_Car_Cd', 'Leg_Dep_Dt_Tm', 'd1_avail', 'cp_avail', 'mn_avail',
       'ot_avail', 'total_seats', 'dest_lat', 'dest_long', 'geometry']].to_json())

cities_input = cities[['Leg_Orig', 'Leg_Dest', 'MAILG_CTY_NM', 'MAILG_ST_CTRY_NM',
                       'Leg_Dep_Dt', 'Opr_Car_Flt_Nbr', 'Leg_Dep_Tm', 'Leg_Arrv_Dt_Tm',
                       'Opr_Car_Cd', 'Leg_Dep_Dt_Tm', 'd1_avail', 'cp_avail', 'mn_avail',
                       'ot_avail', 'total_seats', 'dest_lat', 'dest_long', 'geometry', 'duration_hours']]

city_source = ColumnDataSource(cities.drop('geometry', axis=1))

p1 = Figure(title='Flights',
            plot_height=936,
            plot_width=1560,
            toolbar_location='below',
            tools='pan, wheel_zoom, box_zoom, reset')

p1.xgrid.grid_line_color = None

p1.ygrid.grid_line_color = None  # Add patch renderer to figure.

p1.patches('xs', 'ys', source=geosource,
           fill_color=None,
           line_color='gray',
           line_width=0.25,
           fill_alpha=1)  # Create hover tool

slider_duration = Slider(title='Duration', start=0, end=int(np.round(cities.duration_hours.max(), 0)), step=1, value=12)

callback = CustomJS(args = dict(source=city_source), 
                    code = """source.change.emit();""")
slider_duration.js_on_change('value', callback)

duration_filter = CustomJSFilter(args = dict(slider = slider_duration, 
                                           source = city_source), 
                               code = """
var indices = [];
// iterate through rows of data source and see if each satisfies some constraint
for (var i = 0; i < source.get_length(); i++){
 if (source.data['duration_hours'][i] <= slider.value){
 indices.push(true);
 } else {
 indices.push(false);
 }
}
return indices;
""")

#SEAT FILTER START

slider_seats = Slider(title='Seats', start=0, end=int(cities.total_seats.max()), step=1, value=10)

callback_seats = CustomJS(args = dict(source=city_source), 
                    code = """source.change.emit();""")
slider_seats.js_on_change('value', callback_seats)

seats_filter = CustomJSFilter(args = dict(slider = slider_seats, 
                                           source = city_source), 
                               code = """
var indices = [];
// iterate through rows of data source and see if each satisfies some constraint
for (var i = 0; i < source.get_length(); i++){
 if (source.data['total_seats'][i] >= slider.value){
 indices.push(true);
 } else {
 indices.push(false);
 }
}
return indices;
""")

#SEAT FILTER END

columns =  [TableColumn(field=Ci, title=Ci) for Ci in ['Leg_Orig',  'Leg_Dest',  'MAILG_CTY_NM',  'Opr_Car_Flt_Nbr', 'Leg_Arrv_Dt_Tm',  'd1_avail',  'cp_avail',  'mn_avail',  'total_seats', 'weather_desc',  'duration_hours']]





view = CDSView(source = city_source, filters = [duration_filter, seats_filter])

sites = p1.circle('dest_long', 'dest_lat', source = city_source, color = 'red', 
                 size = 5, alpha = 0.3, view = view)

data_table = DataTable(source=city_source, columns=columns, width=1560, height=280, view= view)

p1.add_tools(HoverTool(renderers = [sites],line_policy='next',
                          tooltips = [('City','@MAILG_CTY_NM'),
                                     ('Departure Time','@Leg_Dep_Dt_Tm'),
                                     ('Seats','@seats'),
                                     ('Flight Time','@duration_hours' + ' hours'),
                                     ('weather', '@weather_desc' + ' low:' + '@low_temp' + ' high:' + '@high_temp' + ' rain:' + '@rain')]))



#city_pt = p1.circle('dest_long', 'dest_lat', source = newsource,
#                       color='red')

layout = column(p1, slider_duration, slider_seats,data_table)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```